# How do I forEach on runCommand result

Tags: mongodb

I got `E QUERY    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forEach'`

How could I for each the result ?

```
cur = db[source_collection].runCommand('aggregate',
  pipeline: pipeline
  allowDiskUse: true)
cur.forEach (customer) ->
  db[output_collection].update({'_id': customer._id},{
          '$pull': {
              '$records.items': {
                  $regex: /\s+/
              }
          }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) helper instead since in 2.6 and later, the [**`aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) helper always returns a cursor:

```
cur = db[source_collection].aggregate pipeline
cur.forEach (customer) ->
    db[output_collection].update('_id': customer._id,
        '$pull': 
            'records.$.items': 
                '$regex': /\s+/       
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [mongo aggregation runCommand](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/)  documentation

> Using the aggregate command to return a cursor is a low-level operation, intended for authors of drivers.

and

> runCommand returns a document that contains results

so you write `cur.result.forEach`

Answer (score 0):

It is old but even though I will right this:

For the first case I think it will help:

```
cur.result.forEach(
   function(doc)
   {
      ...
      ...

   })
```

I have more one that can I add more for future questions around it:

```
db.runCommand(
   { aggregate: "MyCollectionName",
     pipeline: [
                 { $group : 
                     { 
                        _id : "$GroupColumnName"
                        ,"count": { "$sum": 1 }
                        , AllDocs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
                     } 
                 },
                 { "$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }
               ],
     allowDiskUse: true
   }
).result.forEach(
   function(doc)
   {
       doc.AllDocs.forEach(
            function(docInternal)
            {
                print(docInternal._id);
            }
       );
   })
```